# Excel - Extract Test Between Semi-Colon

Tags: excel-formula

I am have a list of data in Column A with different lengths in the following format:

```
ABC Radiologist 100; ABC Nurse 200; ABC Technologist 300; ABC Biller 400; ABC Coder 500
```

I am trying to extract each line of data into a separate column to show as such:

```
Course 1             Course 2       etc
ABC Radiologist 100  ABC Nurse 200
```

I need each course name to be in a separate column.

I used this formula in column B:

```
=MID(A1,1,SEARCH(";",A1)-1)
```

and this formula in Column C:

```
=TRIM(MID($A$1,LEN(B1)+2,FIND(";",$A$1,LEN(B1))))
```

This formula returns values, but because of the varying lengths of the data, in Column C, it cuts the data off or adds data after the third ;

Any suggestions?

I need to repeat this formula up to 9 times

Comment: Text to Columns, it is on the Data tab.

Comment: The data in Column A is a formula that is pulling all the courses together. When I try to use the Text to Columns, it copies over the formula

Comment: Copy and paste special the values to column B then use Text to Columns on that.

Comment: Thanks! That works - Except the table the data is in is dynamic. There will be new lines being added with new courses. Is the easiest way to just copy and past the data as test in column B every time it updates?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use vba that leverages text to columns and automate it.

Comment: do you have an example of the vba code I would use?

Comment: Not off hand but google might.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, enter this in **B1**:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

We are copying **B1** across.  So **C1** would contain:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999))
```

and **D1** would contain:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:C)*999-998,999))
```

etc.

Comment: What would the formula in Column C be? It seems to be repeating everything in Column B

Comment: @PhillyConsultant  See my **EDIT#1**